# Compare two xml files using VBS in QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I need to compare 2 xml files using QTP where the values for each tag needs to be compared and need to print the difference in values if found. I used the built in Function **XMLUTIL** but its not working as expected i.e.. its creates a file with differences including the parent tag.

```
<tns:AAL_Request_NEW xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bnymellon.com/AAL_Request_NEW  AAL_Request_NEW.xsd">
  <tns:OPF_Information>
    <tns:Source>
      <tns:Source>EPH</tns:Source>
    </tns:Source>
    <tns:References>
      <tns:Accounting_Record_Reference>130830000672401</tns:Accounting_Record_Reference>
      <tns:OPF_Reference>EPH1308300006724</tns:OPF_Reference>
      <tns:Group_Reference>EPH1308300006723</tns:Group_Reference>
    </tns:References>
  </tns:OPF_Information>
</tns:AAL_Request_NEW>
```

In the above xml file i just need the tags with values like

tns:Source with value **EPH**, tns:Accounting_Record_Reference with value 130830000672401, tns:OPF_Reference with value EPH1308300006724 and tns:Group_Reference EPH1308300006723 to be compared and not the parent tags like tns:References, tns:OPF_Information or tns:AAL_Request_NEW.

Can anyone help with the logic to fetch the tags which has no child tag inside it and ends immediately with having only a value between its start <> and end  and compare it with the other file and print the tag name and the values if there is a difference?

Answer (score 0):

you can use CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") to read the xml files and retrive the tags by tag name and comparte them both.

```
Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
objXMLDoc.async = False 
objXMLDoc.load("<XML PATH>")

Set Root = objXMLDoc.documentElement 
Set tags = root.tagnames
Set NodeList = Root.getElementsByTagname("<node name>")
For Each Elem In NodeList 
msgbox  Elem.text
Next
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: What if there are missing/additional tags?